# error raise in Activity

Tags: android

**error raise during login process. i dont understand exactly what are problem raise please help to solve**

```
11-11 05:53:17.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.SaxParser2/com.SaxParser2.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1626)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.SaxParser2.Login.onCreate(Login.java:55)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 11 more
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 23 more
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1625)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1725)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:314)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:69)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 27 more
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_light.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1843)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1620)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 31 more
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/color/primary_text_light.xml
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:471)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1825)
11-11 05:53:17.344: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 32 more
```

**My mainClass::**

```
package com.SaxParser2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String RequestID;
    String Status;
    String URL1;
    String ActivityName;
    String AudioScript;
    ListView lview;
    String[] Sturb1;
    String[] Arr_value;
    public static  String str_getValue;
    String[] Stitle1 ;
    ArrayList<String> al_value;

    ListView list1;

    ListViewAdapter lviewAdapter;
    Intent i;
    String Username;
      String Password;
    EditText username,password;
    @Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        i = new Intent(this, Request.class);
         Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);

         button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Username = username.getText().toString();
                 Password = password.getText().toString();
                 if(Username.length()==0)
                 {

                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Fill Username ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } 
                 else if(Password.length()==0)
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Fill Password ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                 }
                 else
                 {
                 System.out.println("Username is "+Username);
                 System.out.println("Password is "+Password);
                 SaxParser(Username,Password);
                    i.putExtra("value", str_getValue);
                    startActivity(i);
                 }








             }
         });
        }




    public void SaxParser(String UserName,String Password) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Username is ::  --- >>> "+UserName);
            System.out.println("Password is  :: ------ >>> "+Password);

            //String url = "http://192.168.1.20/WebServices/Service.asmx/CheckAuthentication?Id="+UserName+"%20&Password="+Password+"";
            String url = "http://203.109.115.55/WebServices/Service.asmx/CheckAuthentication?Id="+UserName+"%20&Password="+Password+"";


            URL sourceUrl = new URL(url);

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            AuthHandler dataHandler = new AuthHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(dataHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
            AuthDataset dataset = dataHandler.getParsednewJobdtl_DataSet();

            System.out.println("dataset.getint1();"+dataset.getint1());
            str_getValue= dataset.getint1();
            /*System.out.println(RequestID);*/
            /*  --------------  Activity name  -------------  */
            /*Arr_value = new String[al_value.size()];
            Arr_value = al_value.toArray(Arr_value);

            System.out.println("Arr_value"+ Arr_value);*/


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Comment: I am sure ResourceNotFound Exception is maninly occur due to a problem of index in R.java file. So better try to `project->clean`

Comment: @Dr.nik Is it with Android 1.5 devices? I am having the same problem, and the accepted solution does not work. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul some time much media resource are raise this kind of issue.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul is there any more help by me?????

Comment: Here is my similar issue: http://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=888

Comment: do you have try with new project?

Comment: I don't think so its the solution for that exception, Because in res/drawable folders we put only those images which are needed for particular screen size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same error trace (from `InflateException` to `FileNotFoundException: res/color/primary_text_light.xml`) and solved it like this:

1. I compared the content of `res/drawable-hdpi` to the content of `res/drawable`
2. I copied all missing files from `res/drawable-hdpi` to `res/drawable`

So I would say: make sure that each of your `res/drawable*` folders contain the same number of images, with the same filenames.

Note: This is very strange, because I never used nor added any file called `primary_text_light.xml`, so I have no idea why Android complained about it in the first place. Anyway, I hope this helps :-)

Comment: I don't think so its the solution for that exception, Because in res/drawable folders we put only those images which are needed for particular screen size.